# How to create xhtml files in an Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Hello I´m writting a plug-in for Eclipse and part of the work of its work is to add new xhtml files in a JSF project.

I wonder what's the best way here. Is there a particular and recommended API for this case or I just have to treat this kind of file as a non-particular one and handle all the contents by myself?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of model-to-text generators (one of them mine, in full disclosure) that can help you if there is some boilerplate you want generated around your structure.  An example of this is how Eclipse can generate getters and setters for Java instance variables.

If you're not familiar with those. though, or if the file content is relatively simple then you might want to just treat your generated xhtml as simple text files and use the basic resource methods to create them.